# Azure Application Insight Javascript Logs Error Constantly

Tags: azure-application-insights

I am using Application Insight for Web Pages(Javascript) and seen that for a particular resource it logs errors constantly because of some extension of the browser. How to avoid such exception caused by another plugins/extension creating load on my server. However, we can't disable(or ask to disable) the extension as its equally important for us.

if anyone out there has encountered this earlier or know the way to avoid exceptions to be tracked which are caused by external plugins.

Comment: You can filter the data, see [this blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/albulank/2016/04/20/modifying-and-filtering-telemetry-with-appinsights-javascript-sdk-telemetry-initializer/). Works for exceptions as well.

Comment: Thank you @PeterBons for the suggestion but this can filter my other important logging. Is there any way to tell application insight to consider the logs that have been generated from internal js and not from the js which are from extension

Comment: No, unless there is some information in the exception (like stacktrace) you can use to make that distinction, then you can use that in a telemetry initializer.

Comment: Try to contact the developers or the enterprise of the plugin, and pass the errors to them. It's preferred to them fix the errors, so then it will not be sent to the server and will consume less of your azure resources. See if trhe extension if youi use hava an update tought